# Why does compiler say Hash is not implemented when I put a HashMap in my struct?

Tags: rust, hashmap, traits, implements

I'm trying to use a HashMap in a very basic way in my struct and I'm confounded by this error ... what am I missing?

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `HashMap<&str, &T>: Hash` is not satisfied
   --> src/file.rs:290:5
    |
282 | #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
    |                         ---- in this derive macro expansion
...
290 |     enums: &'a HashMap<&'a str, &'a T>,
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Hash` is not implemented for `HashMap<&str, &T>`
    |
    = note: required for `&HashMap<&str, &T>` to implement `Hash`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Hash` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Sample Rust Playground: [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ada5a062fc5af5514c9bf02d3720ef52)

`&str` should have all the traits implemented for it yes/no?

Here is the sample-code I'm using to show this issue:

```
    use std::collections::HashMap;
    use std::hash::Hash;

    trait Pt<'a> {
        fn is_int(&self) -> bool;
    }

    #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
    struct Enumeration<'a, T: Pt<'a>>
    where
        T: ?Sized + Eq + Hash,
    {
        pt: &'a T,
        max_length: u8,
        enum_name: &'a str,
        enums: &'a HashMap<&'a str, &'a T>,
        reverse_enums: HashMap<&'a T, &'a str>,
    }
```

Comment: `HashMap` doesn’t have a hash; that its keys or values might have one doesn’t change that.

Answer (score 1):

This error is about `HashMap` **itself** not implementing the `Hash` trait. Which it doesn't, no matter the types of keys and values. And since when you `#[derive(Hash)]` for a struct it requires that all it's elements also implement `Hash` you cannot do it for your outer struct.

You can either resign from implementing `Hash` for `Enumeration`, or you have to do it manually.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are saying.  Eventually, I'll want Enumerator struct to be in another hash, but the problem right now, with this snippet is the derrive portion.  If I comment it out, it compiles.   Ok, I'll leave it like that for now until implement the hash for this struct.

`//#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]`

Comment: @user10658782 If this helped you, then I'm glad. But I feel like this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). It is very strange to put hashmap inside another hashmap as value, and even stranger to use it as a key. Maybe you should rethink your higher design choices.